# My website has been attacked with Laravel smtp crack

Tags: php, laravel

I noticed something strange on my sent mails today. Someone must have injected a crack.How do i solve this matter? Below is the content of the mail:

```
From: mail@wokforge.com
```

Subject: LARAVEL SMTP CRACK | HOST: mail.wokforge.com
To: rahulethan1993@gmail.com

Success Send,
BY XCATZE

URL :http://129.159.148.xx/.env

HOST :mail.wokforge.com

PORT :587

USER :mail@wokforge.com

PASSW :xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

SENDER :unknown@unknown.com

Comment: https://rocoders.com/blog/laravel-smtp-crack-host-or-how-to-have-a-nasty-day , good luck pal

Comment: also https://serverfault.com/questions/1041121/email-smtp-credentials-keep-getting-compromised-every-now-and-then-laravel-7

Comment: also https://laravel-news.com/laravel-smtp-crack

Comment: You can handle it using google reCAPTCHA or patten to solve this.

Comment: Follow the advice in the laravel-news article, and go rotate your credentials for every service you have in your env

Answer (score 4):

Turn off debug mode

```
APP_ENV=production 
APP_DEBUG=false
```

source: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-smtp-crack

Answer (score 0):

Xcatze was made by me To crack smtps
From websites with laravel method
But you can Secure yourself by
Delete env file or rename it and
Turn off Debug mode..

Answer (score -1):

Answered - but adding a comment.

Leaving Laravel in debug mode exposes the error debug screen - so anyone out in the internet can trigger and exception on your website and view all the configuration variables.

An easy way to trigger an exception is to send a POST request to a GET route.